# How do I refresh QWidget to display the current information?

Tags: python, pyside2, qwidget, qtwidgets, qstackedwidget

I have a PySide2 GUI that accepts a number from the user on page one then does some calculations and displays the results on page two. Each page is a QWidget within a QStackedWidget. There is a pushbutton on page two, the results page, that sends the user back to page one to enter a new number.

My problem is that when I enter a new number the results never change from the first number. I use print statements to confirm that the labels on the results page are updating but the display stays the same.

```
# importing the module
import os
import sys
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
import PySide2.QtUiTools as QtUiTools


class IncomeScreen(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(IncomeScreen, self).__init__()

        # Load the IncomeScreen ui
        loader = QtUiTools.QUiLoader()
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "main.ui")
        self.main = loader.load(path, self)

        # Connect the signals with custom slots
        self.main.calculate_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.calculate)

    def calculate(self):
        init_amount = self.main.income_lineEdit.text()
        IncomeScreen.init_amount = float(init_amount)
        # Create an instance of DistributionScreen class
        self.distribution = DistributionScreen()
        # Add DistributionScreen to the stacked widget
        widget.addWidget(self.distribution)
        # Change index to show DownloadPage
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)


class DistributionScreen(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DistributionScreen, self).__init__()
        loader = QtUiTools.QUiLoader()
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "dialog.ui")
        self.dialog = loader.load(path, self)

        # Set initial amount to label
        self.dialog.initialAmount_label.setText(str(IncomeScreen.init_amount))
        print("Initial Amount = {:0.2f}".format(IncomeScreen.init_amount))

        # 10 Percent
        ten = IncomeScreen.init_amount * 0.1
        print("10% = {:0.2f}".format(ten))
        self.dialog.label_10percent.setText("{:0.2f}".format(ten))
        print(self.dialog.label_10percent.text())

        # 20 percent
        twenty = IncomeScreen.init_amount * 0.2
        print("20% = {:0.2f}".format(twenty))
        self.dialog.label_20percent.setText("{:0.2f}".format(twenty))
        print(self.dialog.label_20percent.text())

        # Update widget
        self.dialog.update()

        # Connect the signals with custom slots
        self.dialog.reset_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.reset)

    def reset(self):
        print("reset")
        # Change index to show IncomeScreen
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()-1)


# main
# if __name__ == "__main__":
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
income = IncomeScreen()
widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
widget.addWidget(income)
widget.show()
try:
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
except:
    print("Exiting")
```

Also I'm using Python 3.7.4

EDIT: You can download the ui files [here](https://www.mediafire.com/folder/9eay63v5or2z8/qtstackedwidget_refresh_mwe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various problems with your code, but the most important one is that every time `calculate` is called, a new `DistributionScreen` is *added* to the stacked widget, but `widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)` will always go to the *second* index of the stacked widget (which is the *first* instance you created).

A possible simple workaround could be to use the index of the widget returned by `addWidget` or use `setCurrentWidget`:

```
    def calculate(self):
        init_amount = self.main.income_lineEdit.text()
        IncomeScreen.init_amount = float(init_amount)
        self.distribution = DistributionScreen()
        index = widget.addWidget(self.distribution)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(index)
        # alternatively:
        widget.setCurrentWidget(self.distribution)
```

Unfortunately, while this would make your code work, it's not a valid solution, as there are other *important* issues that would create other problems sooner or later:

- a stacked widget works like a tab widget: it's intended to allow *reusability* of the widgets; you should not constantly create a new instance every time, but possibly use the existing one;
- you should *not* set nor use a class attribute for a variable that depends on an instance (as you did with `IncomeScreen.init_amount`);
- you're adding QMainWindows to a stacked widget, which is discouraged, as a main window should be used as a top level window (it has features that rely on that aspect); note that even QDialog is not a valid candidate, and you should opt for a basic QWidget or a container like QFrame or QGroupBox;
- you're using `QUiLoader` to load the widget as a child of the main window, but without adding it to a layout (or setting as central widget), and this will make it unable to resize itself whenever the top level window is resized: if the main window becomes too small, some of the contents won't be visible, if it's too big there will be a lot of unused space;
- you're trying to access a global variable (`widget`) from an instance, while it's not guaranteed that the variable would be valid; in any case, it should *not* be the instance to create new widgets and set the index of the stacked widget, but the stacked widget itself (or any of its ancestors);
- the last try/except block is very dangerous, as it prevents you to capture exceptions (since it's a generic `except:`) or know what was wrong with your program if it crashes;

This is a possible revision of your code (untested, as you didn't provide the `ui` files).

```
import os
import sys
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import PySide2.QtUiTools as QtUiTools


class IncomeScreen(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    # a custom signal to notify that we want to show the distribution page
    # with the provided value
    goToDistribution = QtCore.Signal(float)
    def __init__(self):
        super(IncomeScreen, self).__init__()

        # Load the IncomeScreen ui
        loader = QtUiTools.QUiLoader()
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "main.ui")
        self.main = loader.load(path, self)

        # a proper layout that manages the contents loaded with QUiLoader
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.main)

        # Connect the signals with custom slots
        self.main.calculate_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.calculate)

    def calculate(self):
        init_amount = self.main.income_lineEdit.text()
        self.goToDistribution.emit(float(init_amount))


class DistributionScreen(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    reset = QtCore.Signal()
    def __init__(self):
        super(DistributionScreen, self).__init__()
        loader = QtUiTools.QUiLoader()
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "dialog.ui")
        self.dialog = loader.load(path, self)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.dialog)

        self.dialog.reset_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.reset)

    def setIncome(self, value):
        # Set initial amount to label
        self.dialog.initialAmount_label.setText(str(value))
        print("Initial Amount = {:0.2f}".format(value))

        # 10 Percent
        ten = value * 0.1
        print("10% = {:0.2f}".format(ten))
        self.dialog.label_10percent.setText("{:0.2f}".format(ten))
        print(self.dialog.label_10percent.text())

        # 20 percent
        twenty = value * 0.2
        print("20% = {:0.2f}".format(twenty))
        self.dialog.label_20percent.setText("{:0.2f}".format(twenty))
        print(self.dialog.label_20percent.text())


class MainWidget(QtWidgets.QStackedWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__()
        # create *both* the pages here
        self.income = IncomeScreen()
        self.addWidget(self.income)
        self.distribution = DistributionScreen()
        self.addWidget(self.distribution)

        self.income.goToDistribution.connect(self.goToDistribution)
        self.distribution.reset.connect(self.reset)

    def goToDistribution(self, value):
        # we received the notification signal, then we set the value and 
        # show the related page by switching to it
        self.distribution.setIncome(value)
        self.setCurrentWidget(self.distribution)

    def reset(self):
        self.setCurrentWidget(self.income)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWidget = MainWidget()
    mainWidget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note that:

- if you want a numeric control, you should use [QSpinBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspinbox.html) or [QDoubleSpinBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublespinbox.html) (for floating point numbers), or set a [QIntValidator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qintvalidator.html) or [QDoubleValidator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublevalidator.html), otherwise if the user enters a non numeric value your program will crash (due to the usage of `float()` done without previously checking if the string is actually a valid number);
- while QUiLoader is useful, it has the drawback of always creating a widget, so you can never override its methods; the only solution to this is to use files generated by `pyside-uic` and use the multiple inheritance method, or switch to PyQt and use its `uic.loadUi` which instead allows setting up the UI on the *current* widget;
- most of the problems in your code are due to some tutorials that have been shared lately (some of them on youtube): unfortunately, those tutorials suggest ***a lot*** of terrible things that should ***not*** be done, both for PyQt and Python; I strongly suggest you to look for other resources and, most importantly, always study the documentation.