# PyQt5 and Qwebengine

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I progammed a program that you clicked a button and it opened google. And I put into google window "back" pushbutton when I push button it's switches to previous screen but when I looked task manager there is google tab still open how can I close it? My Whole code on the below. New to the coding please explain like you explain it to baby :)

```
import sqlite3
import sys
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QWidget, QStackedWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, qApp, QFileDialog,QAction
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets

if __name__ == '__main__':
    QtCore.QCoreApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_ShareOpenGLContexts)
    qt_app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)


class ANAEKRAN(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ANAEKRAN, self).__init__()
        loadUi("yeniekran.ui", self)
        self.password.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        app.setStyle("fusion")
        
        self.baglanti_olustur()

        self.login.clicked.connect(self.loginbutton)
        self.register_2.clicked.connect(self.registerbutton)
    
    def baglanti_olustur(self):
        connection = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
        self.cursor = connection.cursor()
        connection.commit()
    
    def loginbutton(self):
        user = self.username.text()
        password = self.password.text()

        self.cursor.execute("Select * From uyegiris where username = ? and password = ?", (user, password))
        data = self.cursor.fetchall()

        if len(user) == 0 or len(password) == 0:
            self.error.setText("Please fill in all fields!")
        
        else:
            if len(data) == 0:
                self.error.setText("There is no such user!")
            else:
                data == password
                self.error.setText("")
                srch = searchengine()
                widget.addWidget(srch)
                widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)

    def registerbutton(self):
        registersc = RegisterScreen()
        widget.addWidget(registersc)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)

class RegisterScreen(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(RegisterScreen, self).__init__()
        loadUi("kayitekrani.ui", self)
        self.createacc.clicked.connect(self.createaccount)
        self.back.clicked.connect(self.homescreen)

    def createaccount(self):
        user = self.username.text()
        passw = self.password.text()
        passw2 = self.password_2.text()

        if len(user) == 0 or len(passw) == 0 or len(passw2) == 0:
            self.error.setText("Please fill in all fields")
        elif passw != passw2:
            self.error.setText("Passwords do not match!")
        else:
            connection = sqlite3.connect("database.db")

            connection.execute("INSERT INTO uyegiris VALUES (?,?)", (user,passw))
            connection.commit()
            connection.close()
            srch = searchengine()
            widget.addWidget(srch)
            widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)
        
    def homescreen(self):
        loginsc = ANAEKRAN()
        widget.addWidget(loginsc)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)

class searchengine(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(searchengine, self).__init__()
        loadUi("girisekrani.ui", self)
        
        
        self.google.clicked.connect(self.ggle)
        self.facebook.clicked.connect(self.fcbk)
        self.youtube.clicked.connect(self.ytb)
        self.twitter.clicked.connect(self.twt)
        self.instagram.clicked.connect(self.instag)
        self.reddit.clicked.connect(self.redt)
        self.amazon.clicked.connect(self.amazn)
        self.netflix.clicked.connect(self.netf)
        self.twitch.clicked.connect(self.twtch)
        
        
    def ggle(self):
        gogle = google()
        widget.addWidget(gogle)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)
    def fcbk(self):
        face = facebook()
        widget.addWidget(face)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)
    def ytb(self):
        ytbb= ytb()
        widget.addWidget(ytbb)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)
    def twt(self):
        twtt = twitter()
        widget.addWidget(twtt)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)
    def instag(self):
        ins = insta()
        widget.addWidget(ins)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)
    def redt(self):
        red = reddit()
        widget.addWidget(red)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)
    def amazn(self):
        amaz = amazon()
        widget.addWidget(amaz)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)
    def netf(self):
        net = netflix()
        widget.addWidget(net)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)
    def twtch(self):
        tw = twtch()
        widget.addWidget(tw)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)
    
    
        
class google(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(google, self).__init__()
        loadUi("google.ui", self)
        self.back.clicked.connect(self.bck)
        
        
    def bck(self):
        
        qApp.disconnect()
        srch = searchengine()
        widget.addWidget(srch)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)
        
        
        
class facebook(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(facebook, self).__init__()
        loadUi("facebook.ui", self)
        self.back.clicked.connect(self.bck)
        
    def bck(self):
        srch = searchengine()
        widget.addWidget(srch)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)
class ytb(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ytb, self).__init__()
        loadUi("youtube.ui", self)
        self.back.clicked.connect(self.bck)
        
    def bck(self):
        srch = searchengine()
        widget.addWidget(srch)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)
class twitter(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(twitter, self).__init__()
        loadUi("twitter.ui", self)
        self.back.clicked.connect(self.bck)
        
    def bck(self):
        srch = searchengine()
        widget.addWidget(srch)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)
class insta(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(insta, self).__init__()
        loadUi("instagram.ui", self)
        self.back.clicked.connect(self.bck)
        
    def bck(self):
        srch = searchengine()
        widget.addWidget(srch)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)
class reddit(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(reddit, self).__init__()
        loadUi("reddit.ui", self)
        self.back.clicked.connect(self.bck)
        
    def bck(self):
        srch = searchengine()
        widget.addWidget(srch)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)
class amazon(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(amazon, self).__init__()
        loadUi("amazon.ui", self)
        self.back.clicked.connect(self.bck)
        
    def bck(self):
        srch = searchengine()
        widget.addWidget(srch)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)
class netflix(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(netflix, self).__init__()
        loadUi("netflix.ui", self)
        self.back.clicked.connect(self.bck)
        
    def bck(self):
        srch = searchengine()
        widget.addWidget(srch)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)
class twtch(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(twtch, self).__init__()
        loadUi("twitch.ui", self)
        self.back.clicked.connect(self.bck)
        
    def bck(self):
        srch = searchengine()
        widget.addWidget(srch)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)


        
        

        

        
        
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ana = ANAEKRAN()
widget = QStackedWidget()
widget.addWidget(ana)
widget.setFixedHeight(480)
widget.setFixedWidth(720)
widget.setWindowTitle("SABO")
widget.show()
try:
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
except:
    print("Çıkış Yapılıyor...")
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Despite what suggested by the tutorial you're following, you should **not** continuously add widgets to the QStackedWidget, which fundamentally works like tab widget, but without tabs: you don't add new tabs, you switch them. See the last part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69534216). Then: 1. don't add QDialog (or QMainWindow) to QStackedWidget, they're intended as top level windows, use QWidget; 2. ignore that tutorial, as it suggests *a lot* of terrible bad practices.

Comment: You must *never* create more than one instance of `QApplication`, so remove `qt_app`. Then move the `if __name__ == __main__` statement to the bottom and put the last block of code inside it. Also, never use a bare `except`, as it makes debugging unnecessarily difficult - you ***need*** to see those tracebacks!